# Interpreting Standardized Residuals vs Predicted Graph

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, residuals

I am performing a regression predicting difficulties with daily tasks, which can range from none to cannot do.  There are many variables between those values, but it is a bounded dependent variable ultimately.

In evaluating the residuals vs. predicted graph, there is a hard limit and downward slope.  [image: Standardized Residuals vs.Predicted Value Graph]

I used a square root transformation of the dependent variable to see if it helps, though a similar pattern emerges.

[image: Residual Vs. Predicted after SqRt Transformation]

In prior posts on this topic, I have seen many recommend re-working the analyses as various other forms of regression such as binning the results and performing multinomial logistic regression.  However, in this model the standardized residual histogram is normal, the qq-plot seems normal, and the other results are broadly consistent with theory.

What would be the practical ramifications of moving forward with this model beyond limiting generalizability?

Comment: Which numerical values can the left-hand side take exactly? What are your right-hand side variables and what values can they take? It is entirely possible that your regression is OK and the plots show structure because of the scales of the variables.

Comment: Thank you for following up on this.  The predicted value could range from 0-3, which is an average of 10 items that range from 0-3.  The predictors have a range of variables, some from 0-7, others 0-300, with 9 variables in that prediction range.